# Uniq table by 1 column

Tags: mysql

I have such structure: table `hits` with the following sample data:

```
page_alpha_id   ok_id               ip
-------------   ------------    -----------
zfuUnu4K11R9C   100255884520    95.73.30.67
wL77qKOmSTFW    100279470528    91.39.146.76
OArxea90        100307614632    176.50.251.94
yuSb4zzRs       100326443828    93.88.21.86
OxyCtgwlwRFX    100356656755    93.223.88.254
ukwY8SpBT5crX   100375258476    81.4.193.238
ifmgtm7QC       100488290479    95.71.3.15
```

How can I `DELETE` rows with duplicates in column `ok_id`?

It doesn't matter which row is deleted.

Comment: if there are duplicates, which is the one you want to keep?

Comment: @typau But even if it isn't important you should choose and specify some criterion. The earliest one added? The first one sorted lexically by IP, by page_alpha_id? (we can't help you devise a query without all the requirements)

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't matter which record you want to keep, you could use something like this:

```
DELETE hits
FROM
  hits INNER JOIN hits h2
  ON hits.ok_id=h2.ok_id AND hits.page_alpha_id >h2.page_alpha_id
```

this will keep only the rows with the least page_alpha_id, that has to be unique.